# PhoneGap (iPhone / Xcode 4) All links open in Safari

Tags: iphone, xcode, safari, cordova

I installed PhoneGap in Xcode but every link I place in the HTML open in Safari, is there a way to get around this? (Even window.location = ''; opens safari)

Also does anyone know how you can start with a remote address instead of a local?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've never used it, but often see others referencing the [ChildBrowser plugin](https://github.com/purplecabbage/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/iPhone/ChildBrowser), which looks like it may fit your needs. You can check out the [readme.txt](https://github.com/purplecabbage/phonegap-plugins/blob/master/iPhone/ChildBrowser/README.txt) for more info.

Comment: I don't see how this addresses the weird behavior the OP is asking about. The default behavior of the platform is not to open Safari, so why are his links opening Safari?

Answer (score 1):

Late response, but here's what I found out if anyone stumbles across this that doesn't require using the ChildBrowser plugin mentioned earlier.

**Cordova.plist** (found in the Supporting Files folder) has some settings for determining this behavior:

- The URLs need to be added to "`ExternalHosts`" in order for them to be whitelisted (add as
  many as needed & you can use * as a wildcard).
- Set "`OpenAllWhitelistURLsInWebView`" to `YES`.

There might be other settings worth configuring there as well, but those two should prevent links & window.location from opening via Mobile Safari.